# In which field does 3d graph plotting used?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, 3d

We know that we can plot 3d graphs in MatPlotLib but in which field does it used and for what purpose

Answer (score 3):

3D graphs are used when you need to establish the relationship between 3 variables(x,y and z).

This application can be used in the following fields:

1)geographical area: In this field X,Y is used as latitude,longitude and Z can be used as Altitude to replicate the geographical area like hills,buildings etc..

2)Geometry: To visualize the 3d objects like plane,sphere,cube etc in three dimensional space we use 3d plotting.

3)Statistics: To compare two variables on third variable we use 3d plots like 3d barchart, Scatter plot etc..

There are many other fields where 3d plotting is used instead of 2d plot, as it provides more information visually.

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with 3 variables and want to plot a graph in between them and identify the relationship between them then you should use 3d graphs.

There can be many use cases of 3d plots:

1. To describe the position of a point in a plane if the position varies with time, we now need 3 measurements- x-axis distance, y-axis distance, and time elapsed.
2. To describe the position of a point in 3D space, we need 3 measurements: x distance, y distance and z distance.
3. To describe the position of a point in 3D space, if the position varies with time, we need 4 measurements: x distance, y distance, z distance and time.

Each of those measurements represents a dimension, and each dimension requires it’s own axis.

Follow this [docs](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-easy-introduction-to-3d-plotting-with-matplotlib-801561999725) for more information